# How to prove using math induction that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\sum ^{n}_{i=1}i^{2}=\frac{1}{6}n\left( n+1\right) \left(2n +1\right)$?

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Use mathematical induction to prove that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$,
$$\sum ^{n}_{i=1}i^{2}=\dfrac {n\left( n+1\right) \left(2n +1\right) }{6}$$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you already prove the base case $\;n=1\;$ ? Did you make some advance in the case $\;n+1\;$ assuming the equation is true for $\;n\;$ ?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE ! People here are willing to help but not to do your homework. So, explain what you already tried and tell where you are stuck. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True for $n=1$. Then, assuming the induction hypothesis (IH) holds for $n \geq 1$,
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^2 &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 + (n+1)^2 \stackrel{\rm(IH)}{=} \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + (n+1)^2 \\
&= \frac{n+1}{6}\left(n(2n+1)+6(n+1)\right) = \frac{n+1}{6}\left(2n^2+7n+6\right)
\end{align*}$$
and you conclude by observing that $(n+2)(2(n+1)+1) = 2n^2+7n+6$ indeed, then by invoking the induction principle.